# Embed PHP-app into Django rendered HTML template

Tags: php, python, django, templates, embed

So I'm working on a bridge between Django and Flarum. Bridging the user session and data is one thing I will have to take care of, but there is something else bugging me:

How would I go about embedding Flarum in a Django-rendered page?

It's PHP-code so the easiest way would be to create a subdomain or subpath and make my webserver expect PHP there. But then I'd need to create an interface for all the data that Django would serve on that page outside the Flarum-wrapper so that Flarum or some custom PHP-code can serve those parts instead. Surely I could use an iframe as well, but I don't think that's a good solution.

Another way would be to somehow make Django work with inline PHP code in the template or even allow a PHP include and prerender it or maybe make the webserver do some black magic.

The thing is I don't know how I would go about embedding the PHP-code in the HTML template that Django uses for rendering the page. I know that normally you shouldn't mix the two and rather reimplement everything in Python but this is not an option here.

I'd be happy about any hints you could provide. The dream would be a template tag like {% include php "/path/to/phpscript %} and be done with it.

Comment: why not just `os.popen("php /path/to/a_file.php").read()` ? it may not work quite how you want though ... im not sure ...

Comment: Yeah that's the point. I have no idea if it would work how I'd want it. From what I understand Flarum has PHP code that renders it but then again it uses PHP in a backend to serve a connection to the database.

If I do it this way then I'd need to serve the PHP-backend for the js-portion of Flarum still (which would not be a problem).

What do you think could be something that I would not expect of using this command?

Comment: why are you trying to "embed" it? maybe just use the API to get relevant data and then render it in django?

Comment: There is PHP-code involved in rendering Flarum and in providing a database-connection. The latter is not the issue here but the former.

Do you imply I should rewrite the rendering PHP-code in Python?

Comment: or I guess you could just embed a flarum.php url in an <iframe> I guess ... but if you want to interact with the data I would recommend using flarums API or direct database access to get relevant data

Comment: As I said in the original post I don't want to resort to iframes due to the inconveniences connected to that approach.